# Missing return statement in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I fall in a strange problem of PhpStorm. I'm using the trial version of 2016.1, I've this method inside my own class:

```
/**
 * Set arbitrary log
 * @param $level string level of the error message
 * @param $mex string The message
 * @param $ctx array context of the problem
 */

public function log($level, $mex, array $ctx = array())
{
    $mex = $this->Message($level, $mex, $ctx);
    $this->write($mex);
}
```

Now PhpStorm underlined in green all the php doc with this message:

> Missing @return tag in function/method PHPDOC comment

but I missing the `@return` 'cause I don't need it in this function. I only need to store the information passed as parameter inside another method.

Is a PhpStorm bug or I did wrong something?

Comment: It may depend on your inspection settings (check Inspections for PHPDoc in Settings/Preferences). But your method alone is fine -- no `@return` is not required here -- maybe if you provide whole class.... In any case: try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: @LazyOne Tried with your solution, still not working.

Comment: Place caret somewhere in the error place and invoke Alt+Enter -- you should see what inspection triggers it. Please post a screenshot of what you see there. Now, use `arrow right` key and expand submenu, choose "Edit Inspection" -- show a screenshot of hat you see (which inspection is that and what settings it has (if any))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of documentation, you could you use:

```
@return void
```

Comment: Why is that strange? That's absolutely fine - and the only correct way here. Always declare it as void if it by design does not return anything. Please read [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2015/10/05/return-null-vs-return-void/), as well.

Comment: It's strange because 99% of the time, PhpStorm doesn't complain about missing `@return` tags in functions that never return a value, which is normal (that tag is only necessary if something is returned). There seems to be no telling when or why the IDE does this sometimes.

Comment: Yes, this is what the PHP docs recommend. But it is indeed strange and also arguably technically wrong. A missing return statement will cause the function to implicitly return `NULL`, which is not the same as `void`. Also see: https://code.garyjones.co.uk/why-return-void-is-wrong

Answer (score 3):

My class method in which it was highlighting the warning "missing @return tag in function/method" was implementing an interface and the PHPDoc for that method in the interface had a "*@return* mixed".

Now I am not returning anything in my actual method, so I changed PHPDoc in the interface to "*@return* void". Looks like it fixed the problem.(there is no more warning through the code inspection).